# Size of document changes when printed in paper, and size of PDF changes when included as is

Tags: margins, include

I am using [this LaTeX template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/phduio-article-based-thesis/vnhkzpyyddvh) for an academic thesis.

I have two problems with the size of the page:

1. When the document is displayed on a screen, it shows the normal page margins you'd expect. However, when I print it in paper, it gives more margin in the right. I would like the printed copy to be as the one I see in the screen.
2. I use the `\includearticle` command the template provides in order to include PDFs into the document. But this command shrinks the size of the document?

This is the definition of the deinition the template provides for `\includearticle`, in the `phduio.cls` file:

```
%% Include PDFs containing separate papers
%% Based on code by Dag Langmyhr
\newcommand{\includearticle}[2][]
{
    \cleartorecto

    \def \ps@default
    {
        \let \@mkboth\@gobbletwo
        \let \@oddhead\@empty
        \def \@oddfoot{\hfil\sffamily\thepage}
        \let \@evenhead\@empty
        \def \@evenfoot{\sffamily\thepage\hfil}
    }

    \def \phduio@ps{default}

    \def \ps@low
    {
        \let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
        \let\@oddhead\@empty
        \def\@oddfoot{\hfil\raisebox{-7.5mm}{\sffamily\thepage}}
        \let\@evenhead\@empty
        \def\@evenfoot{\raisebox{-7.5mm}{\sffamily\thepage}\hfil}
    }

    \let \ps@none = \ps@empty

    \setkeys{phduio@keys}{#1}

    \includepdf[pages = {-}, pagecommand = {\thispagestyle{\phduio@ps}}]{#2}
}

\define@key{phduio@keys}{numbers}{ \def \phduio@ps{#1} }
```

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) we cannot do anything with the code you provide, please post something we can test as is. (3) When printing, have you switched of any scaling in your PDF viewer? Is the paper size in the PDF even available to print on (where I am a lot of theses are made using B5, but there is no physical B5 paper, it has to be printed on A4 and trimmed). As you can see, we need a lot more information.

Comment: The latex document in question is this one : https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/phduio-article-based-thesis/vnhkzpyyddvh

Comment: Please note that we generally do not want to got to external sources to find an mwe. External sources makes your question un usable for others in the future as the document you are pointing to are likely gone.